# multiple images uploading and converting them to thumbnails in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Please can anyone help me out in finding the best imagecomponent for uploading, resizing, cropping.
And little help is needed in this following code.....

index.ctp

```
<?php
 echo $this->form->create(array('type'=>'file'));
 echo $this->form->input('upload',array('type'=>'file','multiple'));
 echo $this->form->end('submit');
?>
```

if I try to print the file info in TestsController.php

```
 <?php 
  class TestsController extends  AppController{

     public function index(){
        // echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->data);
  }
}
?>
```

it ends up with an empty Array() ....is there any other way around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

help for your code..

```
    pr( $this->request->data );
    // user $this->request->data instead of $this->data
    //for printing submitted values
```

and for image there is many component available you can use according your need..........
can visit these links..
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles?by=crop

http://labs.iamkoa.net/2007/10/23/image-upload-component-cakephp/

Comment: @nrao3202287 Thanks sir,if you have got your answer please click on answered and help others..

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need: [Uploader](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader)

I hope you are using 2.x version of cake.